# What is the difference between Lagrangian and Eulerian description in Plasma?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, flow, simulations, plasma-physics

I'm going to study plasma characteristics by using Particle-In-Cell (PIC) method and I know that plasma has fluid behaviour and can also consider as particle behaviour also. To understand a basic of PIC simulation, I would like to understand an origin of the PIC that why it used differential equation to describe plasma properties from Eulerian method? and what is the difference between [Lagrangian and Eulerian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) for plasma physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the varying shape of a deformable medium against some benchmark configuration, we use $\bf X$ to denote the initial position occupied by a particle at $t=0$. At  another time $t$, the particle finds itself in a new place
$$
 {\bf x}~=~{\bf f}({\bf X},\,t)\,~, \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
 $$
where the function ${\bf f}({\bf X},\,t)$ is a trajectory, i.e., a solution to the equation of motion, with the initial condition $\,{\bf x}={\bf X}~$ set at $t=0$.

The current values of all physical and kinematic properties of the medium can be expressed as functions of the instantaneous coordinates ${\bf x}$ of a point where these properties are being measured at the present moment $t$. When referred to the present time and position, such properties are named *Eulerian* and are equipped with a subscript *E*; for example: $\,q_{_E}({\bf x},\,t)\,$. The Eulerian description is fit to answer the question `where' and therefore is convenient in fluid dynamics where the displacement $\,{\bf x}-{\bf X}\,$ can become arbitrarily large and the initial position $\,{\bf X}\,$ is soon forgotten.

While ${\bf x}$ denotes a place in space, the initial condition ${\bf X}$ acts as the `number' of a particle residing at the place ${\bf x}$ presently. Although located now at ${\bf x}$, the particle originally came from ${\bf X}$ and will carry the label ${\bf X}$ forever.

Knowing the trajectories of all particles, we can express the properties as functions of the time $t$ and the initial conditions ${\bf X}$. To that end, we employ the change of variables (1). Expressed through the initial conditions, a property $q$ will be termed as *Lagrangian* and equipped with the subscript *L*:
$$
 q_{_L}({\bf X},\,t)~\equiv~q_{_E}({\bf x}\,,~t)
 $$
or, in more detail:
$$
 q_{_L}({\bf X},\,t)~\equiv~q_{_E}(\,{\bf f}({\bf X}\,,\,t)\,,~t\,)\,~.
 $$
So $q_{_L}$ has the same value as $q_{_E}$, but has a different functional form, for it is now understood as a function of the initial conditions
(the particles' 'numbers') ${\bf X}$, and not of the present-time coordinates ${\bf x}$. Relating the quantities to the initial positions ${\bf X}$, the Lagrangian description tells us `which particle' and is thus practical in description of deformable solids.

To describe a flow of liquid or plasma, the Eulerian picture is better fit.