# Is it true that particle-in-cell (PIC) simulation apply both Lagranian/Eulerian method in?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, plasma-physics

I'm learning about particle-in-cell (PIC simulation) of plasma and I'm having some questions on the description of PIC method. I still have somes questions how PIC simulation works with Eulerian and Lagrangian method? In my understanding, when PIC simulation calculated many plasma quantities, such as, charge density, potential, or electric field in electrostatic that correlate with Poisson's equation:

\begin{equation*}
\nabla^{2} \phi = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}, \qquad \mathrm{where}  \\
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}, \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \mathbf{E} = -\nabla \phi.  
\end{equation*}

Hence, these particle fields will be updated in the Newton's second law or Lorentz equation charged particles

\begin{equation*}
m\frac{\partial ^{2}\mathbf{x}}{\partial t^{2}} = q\left( \mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}\right) .
\end{equation*}

From the steps of determining particle field trough the Lorentz euqation by differential euqation with fixed space. Is this mean PIC simulation applying Eulerian method? Then to move particle (or particle tracking), the PIC will use integration of acceleration and velocity to obtain particle pathway with velocity and position. Is it using Lagrangian picture to observe motion of particle? Since the position and velocity are defined that

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{v}=\int\left(\frac{\partial ^{2}\mathbf{x}}{\partial t^{2}}\right)\mathrm{d}t = \mathbf{v}_{0}+\int \frac{q}{m}\left( \mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{B}\right)\mathrm{d}t, \\
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_{0}+\int\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathrm{d}t  .
\end{equation*}

Is it true that PIC simulation are using both Eulerian and Lagrangian in a process?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768064/2451

Comment: This is a very broad question.

Comment: My experience with PIC is somewhat limited, but every doc & code I've ever seen says they're just solving a pair of coupled differential equations (position + velocity/momentum). Eulerian and Lagrangian are usually describing fluid flows in my experience, rather than particles.

Comment: I think they use one or the other, not both (if either).  Some PIC codes solve things implicitly (called Implicit PIC) while others solve things explicitly (Explicit PIC).  Some work in 3D space and time while others work in frequency-wavenumber space.  It just depends on the code.